# how to use reduce for array slice combination

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

actually i achieved this format in normal for but i'm trying this with reduce method in javascript. i want below format from the x variable

```
format: 

    [[1,1,1], [ 1, 1, 0 ],
      [ 1, 0, 0 ],
      [ 0, 0, 0 ]];


var x = [1,1,1,0,0,0];


var y = [];
y = x.reduce((data,val,i,arr)=>{
    console.log(data.length,i);
     i%2==0 ? data.push(arr.slice(i,i+3)):data.push(arr.slice(i,i+3));
console.log(data);
return data;
    },[]);

 console.log("check y",y);
```

output:

```
check y [ [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 0 ] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a new array and map the parts by slicing the given array.

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    size = 3,
    result = Array.from(
        { length: x.length - size + 1 },
        (_, i) => x.slice(i, i + size)
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Neat, the question is flawed since the point of reduce is to output a single value, not an array